# How to close an NSWindow on Cmd+W without Menu Shortcut?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, nswindow, keydown

i'm porting a Windows application to Mac OS X Cocoa and it must be as similar as possible, so there is no "Close Window" Menu Item with a binded Shortcut in my menu.

But still i would like to be able to close them by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> Shortcut, is there a way to do this without handling keyDown event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately i've implemented the *Close* `menu item` in my *Main Menu* that sends `performClose` to `First Responder` and has the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut.